# type error when trying to update a table field name query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query where i am trying to update field by taking the left number of characters before a space.
I'm not very good with Access VBA, so I'm trying to do this via a query.

my data is a list of SKUs, where I want to update the same field (sku) with a shorter SKU number, by using  the Left$ function along with the InStr function to take all characters to the left of a space in the number.

test sku
E349CAJ6 OBROBRO
E357CAJ6 OBROSID
E329CAJ6 OWHIBRO
E358CAJ6 ONO SID

Note that the space isn't always in position 9, sometimes it varies.   I was trying to use the following Query update value:  Left$([IMPORT - EFF ORDERS]![SKU], InStr([IMPORT - EFF ORDERS]![SKU]," ",1))

The InStr, identifies the starting position based on the space, to use for the Left function.

The SKU field is a Short Text type field.

However, when I run the query, I get a "Type Conversion" error and none of the records will update.

I have wracked my brain to try to figure this one out and would appreciate an expert's fresh eyes on it.

Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: Edit question to show the full query SQL statement. The `,1` is in wrong argument, really don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The `,1` is in wrong argument, really don't need it. If you want to use Compare argument then also use Start argument. Without explicit Start and Compare parameters, function will use defaults.

`Left([IMPORT - EFF ORDERS]![SKU], InStr(1, [IMPORT - EFF ORDERS]![SKU], " ", 1))`

InStr() in this case is returning a value that will be used as a length parameter, not a starting position. Start position for Left is first character.

Comment: Thank you June7.   I think the 1 was a typo.  Here's my calculation :   Left$([IMPORT - EFF ORDERS]![SKU],InStr([IMPORT - EFF ORDERS]![SKU]," ",1))    I'll see if i can upload the Access file so you can evaluate it with more context.

Comment: Looks like same expression. My answer still applies. This site does not support uploading files. I know you have this question on another forum that does allow upload.